# Whats wrong with my python script? Does not print variable

Tags: python

Working through a Python tutorial. I created a simple script (myFirstFunction) that does not perform whats expected.
I expected a line of output that is just two variables multiplied together:

```
apples = raw_input("How many apples do you have?")
oranges = raw_input("How many oranges do you have?")

def myFirstFunction(apples, oranges):
    total_fruit = apples * oranges
    print total_fruit
```

The script does ask for the inputs as expected, but does not print out the results?

```
myName-MacBook:pythonhard me$ python ex19b.py
How many apples do you have?2
How many oranges do you have?2
myNames-MacBook:pythonhard me$
```

Why does it not print out 4?

Comment: You are never calling the function...

Comment: Because you are not calling `myFirstFunction` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You never call `myFirstFunction`.  This can be done by placing this at the end of your script:

   ```
   myFirstFunction(apples, oranges)
   ```
2. [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) always returns a string object.  So, the inputs need to be converted into integers before you multiply them inside `myFirstFunction`.  You can do this by placing them in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int):

   ```
   apples = int(raw_input("How many apples do you have?"))
   oranges = int(raw_input("How many oranges do you have?"))
   ```

---

Here is a fixed version of your script:

```
apples = int(raw_input("How many apples do you have?"))
oranges = int(raw_input("How many oranges do you have?"))

def myFirstFunction(apples, oranges):
    total_fruit = apples * oranges
    print total_fruit

myFirstFunction(apples, oranges)
```

Demo:

```
How many apples do you have?2
How many oranges do you have?2
4
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I got it now, accepting when the time limit comes of

Answer (score 2):

You need to a) call the function & b) convert the input to integers because the result of a `raw_input` is a string.

```
def myFirstFunction(apples, oranges):
    total_fruit = int(apples) * int(oranges)
    print total_fruit

apples = raw_input("How many apples do you have?")
oranges = raw_input("How many oranges do you have?")

myFirstFunction(apples, oranges)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have

```
return total_fruit
```

in function, then call myFirstFunction and print result:

```
def myFirstFunction(apples, oranges):
   total_fruit = apples * oranges
   return total_fruit

apples = raw_input("How many apples do you have?")
oranges = raw_input("How many oranges do you have?")

print myFirstFunction(apples, oranges)
```

or just call myFirstFunction (when no return):

```
myFirstFunction(apples, oranges)
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me about "return".